# How can I Require a public Variable (Prefab) to have a certain component (RigidBody) in UNITY?

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, instantiation, gameobject

I'm trying to implement a "Shoot" MonoBehaviour.
I want it to do something very simple, it should take a Prefab as "Input" (storing it in a "projectile" public variable for the time being), and then simply Instantiate it and add a Forward force to it's RigidBody (relative to the object it is attached to, for example, a Tank).

However, I don't want my game to crash if I accidentally insert a Prefab that doesn't have a RigidBody. (In fact, it would be great if it didn't even allow me to add Prefabs without RigidBodies as projectiles).

I've tried using the "RequireComponent" attribute, but it looks like it only works for classes. Is there any way to do this without having to check if the Projectile has a RigidBody each time I want to shoot it?

I tried the Code Below, but it gives me an error saying I can't Instantiate a RigidBody as a GameObject. Which is understandable, but I'm running out of ideas here.

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody projectile;
    public float firePower = 5f;

    public void Fire()
    {
        GameObject projectileInstance = Instantiate(projectile) as GameObject;
        //maybe add some particles/smoke effect
        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(firePower * transform.forward);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others here already gave you some examples on how you would do this at runtime, however I would recommend you add a `[RequireComponent(typeof(RigidBody))]` to your projectile class (if you have one).

What that does is every time you attach your component to a `gameObject` Unity will automatically add the required components as well without having a performance impact on your game on runtime. Just add this over the class declaration on your projectile script.

You do however need to manually assign your components via the Inspector or by `GetComponent`. But this makes sure that your object has the right components attached.

You need some sort of script on your projectiles for this to work tho. So if you do not have that you should use another option pointed out here.

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a couple questions:

Comment: -Are you suggesting that I should add a Class (for ex: Projectile) which just specifies the Components a basic Projectile is required to have, and then on my Shoot Script Instead of having a public GameObject, create a public Projectile?

Comment: This is all a bit confusing because I'm more used to OOP development, and I'm never quite sure when to add Classes specifying what a GameObject is, because It always looks like I should just be making a prefab instead.

Also can I Instantiate an object in that way if it is In the form of a Script (Projectile class)

Comment: If you come from OOP it's easier to think of a gameObject as your "root" object which has components (aka. actual classes) attached to it. You rarely instantiate C# objects that don't derive from MonoBehaviour, as they only "work" when attached to a gameObject. In short: attach your classes to your gameObject and instantiate it as a prefab.
Regarding my answer: This only works if you have some sort of Script attached to your projectile prefab. If you don't, go with another answer. It would be huge overhead to attach a MonoBehaviour just to require something.

Comment: It IS hovever good practice to let objects themselves handle their components and just interact with them via their own script. (In your specific example: ProjecileScript handles components and has a method to add velocity which you call from your Shoot class) I don't know if it makes sense in your specific case since, as I already said, MonoBehaviours have huge overhead. If you only handle your rigidbody stuff, don't add a own script to each projectile.

Comment: Oops. regarding my first comment: "You rarely instantiate C# objects that don't derive from MonoBehaviour, as they only "work" when attached to a gameObject." should be "You rarely instantiate C# objects that don't derive from MonoBehaviour, because you can't attach them to a gameObject". To use classes that do not derive from MonoBehaviour you would need a structure like this: 

[GameObject] -> [MonoBehaviour] -> [Some arbitrary non-MonoBehaviour class]

Answer (score 2):

You can add in the components that you want at runtime, for example:

```cs
    // First check if there is no rigidbody component on the object
    if (!currentPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()){
        // Add the Rigidbody component
        currentPrefab.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // You can also add a collider here if you want collisions
        var bc = currentPrefab.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

        // And you'll have to calculate the new collider's bounds
        Renderer[] r = t.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++) {
            bc.bounds.Encapsulate(r[i].bounds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a check on the prefab to see if it has a Rigidbody component like so:

```
if (currentPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()){

    // Do something

}
```

The GameObject.GetComponent() method will return null if the type you enter as a parameter is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are already on the write track. You just have to fix your error by doing the following :

```
public Rigidbody projectile;
public float firePower = 5f;

public void Fire()
{
    if( projectile == null )
    {
         Debug.LogError( "You forgot to provide a projectile prefab");
         return;
    }
    Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(projectile) as Rigidbody;
    projectileInstance.AddForce(firePower * transform.forward);
}
```

However, with this method, you can't require the prefab to have multiple components. If you need this, then, go with the method provided by the other answers.